# Parameter not set still passing value in stored procedure sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[XXXXX]
@type varchar(20)
,@Name varchar(20)
,@DayVal int
,@MonthVal int
,@YearVal int

AS
BEGIN

If type='yyy'
begin
insert into dbo.destinationDB
(name,Dayval,Monthval,Yearval)
values
(@name,@DayVal,@MonthVal,@YearVal)
```

In the above Stored procedure of SQL Server the parameters @name, @DataVal, @MonthVal, @YearVal is not defined anywhere neither the values are set in any other Stored Procedures or Jobs . But it still passing values and values are updated in the destination table.

Comment: How are you calling your procedure?

Comment: This is an existing procedure and I am unable to locate any job that is calling this SP in the current SQL server.

Comment: Since this isn't real code, who knows. Please try to create a *real* runnable example and then ask a question about it. It's also far from clear what the narrative in the question is asking about.

Comment: Profiler is your friend, invite him in.

Answer (score 2):

If there is another procedure or trigger calling your proc you will find it in the sys.sql_module:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%XXXX%' -- your proc name
```

If it is not there there are at least 3 possible scenarios:

- there is a linked server calling your server
- there is an external application
- someone else is calling it from ssms

Comment: Another one that might be: someone else is inserting directly to the final table, bypassing the SP.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably comparing with `null`, try adding `and type IS NOT NULL`

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The values (some integer values ) getting updated in table since we do an insert here . They are not NULL or there is no where condition to insert .

Comment: @AmitKumar I could misunderstand.  Karl, Tell me how do you exec your procedure, the table you are inserting does not have default values? Because as I've written  the type is null and your if  condition will always pass

Comment: SELECT j.name 
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS s
      WHERE s.job_id = j.job_id
      AND s.command LIKE '%XXXXX%'
  );

Comment: Cannot find a job which runs this procedure as well

Comment: Maybe you have some trigger set ? @Karl

Comment: Is there a way to  find that acorss all Databases in the server? as of now  SELECT 
 t.name AS TableName,
 tr.name AS TriggerName  
FROM sys.triggers tr
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = tr.parent_id
WHERE 
t.name in ('TABLE_NAME(S)_GOES_HERE');   using this not able to find any triggers.